# AttributeError: module 'purchase.views' has no attribute 'viewPDF'

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I get this error after followed an tutorial, and I'm pretty new to this, but cant figure out what is wrong, since i have checked, double checked, triple checked and so on. it's probably a simple error but for me as a beginner it's not simple ;)

> ```
> Exception in thread django-main-thread: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> ```
>
> "c:\users\jenny\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\threading.py",
> line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
> self.run()   File "c:\users\jenny\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\threading.py",
> line 870, in run
> self._target(*self._args, **self.*kwargs)   File "C:\Users\jenny\Documents\OneDrive Jens
> privat\OneDrive\Programmering\Django\Nymoen ERP
> project\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in
> wrapper    fn(*args, **kwargs)   File
> "C:\Users\jenny\Documents\OneDrive Jens
> privat\OneDrive\Programmering\Django\Nymoen ERP
> project\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py",
> line 124, in inner_run
> self.check(display_num_errors=True)   File "C:\Users\jenny\Documents\OneDrive Jens
> privat\OneDrive\Programmering\Django\Nymoen ERP
> project\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line
> 438, in check
> all_issues = checks.run_checks(   File "C:\Users\jenny\Documents\OneDrive Jens
> privat\OneDrive\Programmering\Django\Nymoen ERP
> project\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line
> 77, in run_checks
> new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)   File "C:\Users\jenny\Documents\OneDrive Jens
> privat\OneDrive\Programmering\Django\Nymoen ERP
> project\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in
> check_url_config
> return check_resolver(resolver)   File "C:\Users\jenny\Documents\OneDrive Jens
> privat\OneDrive\Programmering\Django\Nymoen ERP
> project\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in
> check_resolver
> return check_method()   File "C:\Users\jenny\Documents\OneDrive Jens privat\OneDrive\Programmering\Django\Nymoen ERP
> project\env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 446, in
> check
>
> for pattern in self.url_patterns:   File "C:\Users\jenny\Documents\OneDrive Jens
> privat\OneDrive\Programmering\Django\Nymoen ERP
> project\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in
> **get**    res = instance.**dict**[self.name] = self.func(instance)   File "C:\Users\jenny\Documents\OneDrive Jens
> privat\OneDrive\Programmering\Django\Nymoen ERP
> project\env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 632, in
> url_patterns
> patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)   File "C:\Users\jenny\Documents\OneDrive Jens
> privat\OneDrive\Programmering\Django\Nymoen ERP
> project\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in
> **get**    res = instance.**dict**[self.name] = self.func(instance)   File "C:\Users\jenny\Documents\OneDrive Jens
> privat\OneDrive\Programmering\Django\Nymoen ERP
> project\env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 625, in
> urlconf_module
> return import_module(self.urlconf_name)   File "c:\users\jenny\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\importlib_*init**.py",
> line 127, in import_module
> return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "", line 1014, in _gcd_import   File
> "", line 991, in _find_and_load   File
> "", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
> File "", line 671, in _load_unlocked
> File "", line 783, in
> exec_module   File "", line 219, in
> *call_with_frames_removed   File "C:\Users\jenny\Documents\OneDrive Jens privat\OneDrive\Programmering\Django\Nymoen ERP
> project\smb_erp\urls.py", line 21, in 
> path('', include('purchase.urls')),   File "C:\Users\jenny\Documents\OneDrive Jens
> privat\OneDrive\Programmering\Django\Nymoen ERP
> project\env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 34, in
> include
>
> urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)   File "c:\users\jenny\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\importlib_*init**.py",
> line 127, in import_module
> return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "", line 1014, in _gcd_import   File
> "", line 991, in _find_and_load   File
> "", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
> File "", line 671, in _load_unlocked
> File "", line 783, in
> exec_module   File "", line 219, in
> _call_with_frames_removed   File "C:\Users\jenny\Documents\OneDrive Jens privat\OneDrive\Programmering\Django\Nymoen ERP
> project\purchase\urls.py", line 24, in 
> path('pdf_view/', views.viewPDF.as_view(), name="pdf_view"), AttributeError: module 'purchase.views' has no attribute 'viewPDF'

views.py

```
class ViewPDF(View):
def get(self):

    pdf = render_to_pdf('pdf_template.html', data)
    return HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    
    path('register/', views.registerPage, name="register"),
    path('login/', views.loginPage, name="login"),
    path('logout/', views.logoutUser, name="logout"),
    
    path('', views.home, name="home"),
    path('supplier/<str:pk>/', views.supplier, name="supplier"),
    path('products/', views.products, name="products"),
    path('purchase_order/', views.purchase_order, name="purchase_order"),
    path('order_form/', views.createPurchaseOrder, name="create_purchase_order"),
    path('update_order/<str:pk>/', views.updatePurchaseOrder, name="update_order"),
    path('delete_order/<str:pk>', views.deletePurchaseOrder, name="delete_order"),
    path('suppliers/', views.suppliers_list, name="supplierslist"),
    path('create_supplier/', views.createSupplier, name="create_supplier"),
    path('update_supplier/<str:pk>/', views.updateSupplier, name="update_supplier"),
    path('create_product/', views.createProduct, name="create_Product"),
    path('warehouse_list/', views.warehouse, name="warehouse_list"),

    path('pdf_view/', views.viewPDF, name="pdf_view"),
```

Comment: are you importing files from sub folder ? can you please show full urls.py

Comment: I have update my urls.py now.

Comment: Your view is named `ViewPDF` and not `viewPDF`.

Comment: I changed, but still got the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `official` [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/class-based-views/intro/#using-class-based-views)

> Because Django’s URL resolver expects to send the request and associated arguments to a callable function, not a class, class-based views have an as_view() class method which returns a function that can be called when a request arrives for a URL matching the associated pattern.

Change your urls.py from

```
path('pdf_view/',  views.viewPDF, name="pdf_view")
```

To this

```
path('pdf_view/',  views.viewPDF.as_view(), name="pdf_view")
```